# Network request failed for react flask integration

Tags: python, reactjs, react-native, flask

I'm quite new with this react native and flask. The project I'm doing is to pass the value from react app into flask which will the process by using the python. Hence, the problem I had is when I run the code it produce such error

ERROR  Error: [TypeError: Network request failed]

App.js

```
import React, {Component, useEffect, useState} from 'react';
import {
  Text,
  View,
  SafeAreaView,
  TextInput,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

export default function Homescreen() {

  const [data, setData] = useState();
  const [Sl, setSl] = useState(0);
  const [Sw, setSw] = useState(0);
  const [Pl, setPl] = useState(0);
  const [Pw, setPw] = useState(0);

  const saveData = async () => {
    const url = `http://localhost:5000/predict`;

    try {
      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
        Accept: 'application/json',
        body: JSON.stringify({Sl, Sw, Pl, Pw}), // Pass an object with properties
      });

      if (response.ok) {
        const result = await response.json();
        console.log('Data is added successfully:', result);
        setData(result);
      } else {
        console.error(
          'Error fetching data from the server:',
          response.statusText,
        );
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error:', error);
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    saveData(); // Call the function
  }, []); // Empty dependency array means this effect runs once on component mount
```

app.py

```
import numpy as np
from flask import Flask, request, jsonify, render_template
import pickle
from urllib.parse import quote as url_quote
from flask_cors import CORS

# Create flask app
flask_app = Flask(__name__)
model = pickle.load(open("model.pkl", "rb"))


@flask_app.route("/predict", methods=["POST", "GET"])
def predict():
    sl = float(request.json())
    sw = float(request.json())
    pl = float(request.json())
    pw = float(request.json())
    features = [np.array([sl, sw, pl, pw])]
    prediction = model.predict(features)
    return {"prediction": prediction}


if __name__ == "__main__":
    flask_app.run(debug=True)
```

This is the result when I'm open the localhost
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iP8FH.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hqS0P.png)

Comment: what does `model.predict()` return? Is it a `dictionary`, `list`, or something else? Does the it render if you were to simply `return {'prediction' : ''}` from `app.py`?

Comment: model.predict() supposed to produce result in list and yes, return {'prediction' : ''} will show the result on the react app. This app.py will matching the input user with the model file created

Comment: print the `prediction` and ensure that it's in `JSON` format. Try using `jsonify` to format it if required

Comment: still do the same and not do much cannot produce such output. Another thing when I remove the GET method it said method not allowed

Comment: try to call app.py using the url from Postman. See if you can POST from there

Comment: Still the same output have try it so far, but I think there's stg wrong with the python code in terms of how I create response while the react native textinput supposed to return String but I just do string and float conversion vice versa for both. Seems like need to rewire from zero again